# Авторизация на сайтах с авторизацией от браузера с помощью C#

Tags: c#, xamarin

И так, у меня есть некоторый сайт, который запрашивает пароль и логин с помощью диалогового окна САМОГО бразуера.
Вот пример [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне на нем нужно провести авторизацию, но стандарный метод с http-запросами не подходит, ибо это окно - форма браузера, а не сайта. Вопрос в том, как можно реализовать авторизацию с помощью C#? Еще, так как приложение будет кроссплатформенным, хотелось бы идею для Android. Заранее благодарю за ответы!

Comment: Браузер все равно общается с сервером по http. Возьмите Фидлер, запишите запрос и посмотрите что в хедерах авторизации уходит- скорее всего basic.

Comment: Любую програмную работу с HTTP серверами следует начать с изучения протокола HTTP, хотя бы его основ. Далее нужно познакомиться с инструментами разработчика в браузере, научиться просматривать сетевой трафик, запросы и ответы сервера. Не зная как это работает у вас постоянно будут возникать вопросы, ответы на которые вы будете не знать, где искать.